# Error printing pdf files using sockets in C# (multiples pages with weird characters)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, printing, driver

I am facing some problems when I try to print a pdf file using Socket in C#.

I send only one page but the device (printer) print a lot of pages with so weird characters. I will attach an example.

There are different models of Sansung printers in my company. The error happens only for specific models.

All of them are on the internal network and I don't have the driver installed locally. I use only the ip address to print the file.

PS: When I send a txt file the problem doesn't happen.

Below you can find my source code.

```
        var server = "10.247.52.171";
        var nome = "c:\\teste.pdf";

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSocket.NoDelay = true;

        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(server);
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
        clientSocket.Connect(ipep);

        clientSocket.SendFile(nome);
        clientSocket.Close();
```

[Print example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgvvY.jpg)

Comment: Those weird characters are the binary PDF bytes. You cannot just send raw binary file to print.

Comment: Yes .. I solved the problem converting the pdf to pcl file before sending it to the printer. Thanks.